# Why does the Bevel tool breaks my shaders?

Tags: modeling, shaders, bevel

Here is what happens when I use the Bevel tool on my model:
[image]

I tried looking if there wasn't faces overlapping but that doesn't seem to be the case.

What could be causing this issue ?

[model.fbx](https://gofile.io/d/cLMI22)

Comment: Beveling on triangulated faces will create strange geometry. It's not recommended. This could be the source of your breaking normals, or it could be something else.
If you know your faces are still square after the bevel, you'd want to manually flatten your normals. Use the "alt+N->set from faces" command.

Comment: Although there are no faces overlapping before bevel, right at the top you can see that the bevel cannot work properly on the tip of those triangulated faces. As @sybog64 said, this will create strange geometry as you can see for yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the *Object Data panel > Geometry Data*, try to *Clear Custom Split Normals Data* (the split normals are the normals that determine the shading, they may be messed up with some fbx imports):

[image]

Comment: That works well, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your UVs are messed up, go to the *UV Editing* workspace, select all faces and unwrap the object. *Smart UV Project* should work fine for this one.

Comment: I did it and my UVs seem fine (https://imgur.com/9xh41yC), but the problem still occurs. Although this is what I see when I select the edge, not sure if that's normal: https://imgur.com/EJxfEn1

Comment: Try untriangulating the mesh to see if that helps

Comment: How do I do that ?